# validation of a pseudo jpeg compression

Tags: image-processing, dct, compression

I've done something which is not exactly the jpeg algorithm. What I've done is that given an image $I$ of $N\times N$ size, I have computed the DCT of individual $8\times 8$ blocks.

Once this has been done, I have imposed that the top leftmost corner is left intact but the other elements be equalled to zero.

Then i compute the inverse-DCT on that block and use it to reconstruct my image.

The algorithm seems to work giving the following results

[image]

[image]

Given that I've ignored lots of steps in the jpeg algorithm (all the things related to huffman encoding, quantization matrix etc) why is this simple algorithm working?

Thanks.

Comment: Transform coding is the same (DCT). Then you apply a coarse quantization (all but dc terms equal to zero). From here, all JPEG does is only to encode the quantized coefficients (represent the coefficients with a number of bits as small as possible) by applying run length coding, differential coding, and hufman/arithmatic coding on the quantized coefficients. Also note that the dc term has the highest information (which is not quarantized here). That's why a quite sensible picture is reconstructed.

Comment: Happy new year, and a reminder that your question and its answers require some action (votes, acceptance)

Comment: Happy new year, and thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you compute a $8\times 8$ 2D-DCT, and keep the top left corner only, you are keeping a quantity that is proportional to the average of each  $8\times 8$ block.  This is the DC component, similar to the $0$ frequency in a Fourier transform. This works like a JPEG coding with a quantization table looking like:

$$\displaystyle \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
1 & \infty & \cdots & \infty\\
\infty  & \infty  & \cdots & \infty\\
\vdots  & \vdots &  \ddots & \infty\\
\infty  & \infty  & \cdots & \infty
\end{array}\right)$$

Performing the inverse DCT with this "kind of" quantization spreads the average value over the $8\times 8$ block. What you are doing is equivalent to performing a moving average with an $8\times 8$ uniform window and then downsampling by  $8$ in both the $x$ and $y$ directions. You compress by replacing each $64$-pixel  block by its average, resulting (effectively) in a $64$ times smaller image, and you "fake" an original size image by extrapolating the average.

However, you cannot claim a $1/64$ compression yet, because the coefficients you keep are not quantized yet, and are stored for instance on $32$-bit floating point words. Before you go into more advanced coding, you are about at a  $1/16 = 1/64\times 32/8$ compression rate.